# How to open an app in non-retina mode for iPad?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, retina-display

Can we turn off retina display for iPad programmatically? I know it is possible in cocos2d by using

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] enableRetinaDisplay:NO];
```

But for cocos touch is it possible? If yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No,Its not possible. Cocos2d  acts as a engine so its possible to turn off retina display.It creates its own virtual display and show it over the normal display.
But in cocos touch we can not access the actual engine.So its not possible in cocos touch.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but you can't do this in `iOS`. But you can check it ***(retina/not)*** by using following code

Put this method

```
- (BOOL)isRetina
{
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

And write code for non retina screen.

```
if([self isRetina] == NO)
{
  // not retina display
}
else
{
   // retina display
}
```

Using above code you can perform your operation for *not retina display OR retina display* device.

Comment: Yes I know this method. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: that is not really useful answer to the OP, regarding it is about something else which has never been asked.